# What are these birds in episode 5 of Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, object-identification, loki-2021

In season 1 episode 5 of *Loki*, we see a species of birds. What are these birds and what is special about them?

[image: Loki exclaims to the group of Lokis he is following, in the background a group of birds, purple in colour with orb heads floating above their necks, can be seen milling around]

Comment: @ARogueAnt.: Weren't they headless with some orb/sphere floating in its stead ?

Comment: We are still waiting: https://www.thenewsfetcher.com/loki-episode-5-what-are-those-birds-animals-jumping-around-in-the-void/

Comment: “what is special about them?” — sometimes a bird with a floating orb where its head should be is just a bird with a floating orb where its head should be.

Comment: Aren't those peahens? LOL

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi that site also thinks it was Thor in the jar, not Throg, so I would ignore most of what it says.

Comment: Obviously they just didn't have the time to complete the visual effects....

Comment: The elusive snipe

Comment: @JackBNimble - I believe they're snark.

Comment: Long live the freehand circles!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an interview with [Fandom](https://www.fandom.com/articles/loki-kate-herron-season-1-finale-season-2-kang) Kate Herron, the director of *Loki* season 1, explained about the Void birds and their name as Narvas based on the name of show's head of production design, Kasra Farahani's daughter Narva.

> I also love those little Void turkeys. They’re called Narvas, because Kasra pitched the idea of them, so we named them after his daughter, Narva. I love those little creatures.

Comment: Great find! You should probably make this the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 11):

The show's head of production design, Kasra Farahani, describes them as *"Void creatures"*. No additional info is given about them other than that his original concept for the void was a lot weirder and more surreal. Somehow they survived the studio process.

> *"The big giant hands, they were... I don't have a clear story for that one.* [Laughs.] *That was really just a visual thing, because we were trying to find moments to infuse The Void with surrealism. So that was the point of the giant heads, and also of the little Void creatures that look like the little peacocks. Originally, at some point, I was proposing a far more Salvador Dali-esque, Dada-esque version of The Void, and it evolved over time. But those bird creatures and heads made it through from the Dada-esque version to the English moors version of The Void.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Loki's Purple Bird Creatures And Giant Stone Heads Explained By Production Designer](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/2570203/lokis-purple-bird-creatures-giant-stone-heads-explained-production-designer-tom-hiddleston)</sup></sub>

Comment: They are all Loki.

Comment: @user931 I am Spartacus!